# Jquery mouse event

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have no idea on how to fix seemingly a simple problem. If you hover over the album covers there fadesIn an ( i ) icon if you hover over the ( i ) icon there comes up an Tooltip but it doesn't stay up it fadesOut after 1,2sec. How could i fix this that the tooltip stays up when you hover over the ( i ) icon and fadesOut when mouse leaves the icon.

Example here: [http://www.midnightlisteners.com](http://www.midnightlisteners.com/)

my code:

```
//      ( i ) Icon

  $(".play, .more-info").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutIds'));
        $(this).next(".more-info").fadeIn(600);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var someElement = $(this);
        var timeoutIds = setTimeout(function(){
            someElement.next(".more-info").fadeOut('150');
        }, 1200); // giving a shorter time will reduce the fadeout effect
        //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
        someElement.data('timeoutIds', timeoutIds); 
    });
```

//      Tool-Tip

```
  $(".more-info").mouseenter(function(){
      clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
      $(this).find(".the-tooltip").fadeIn('150');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
      var someElement = $(this);
      var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
          someElement.find(".the-tooltip").fadeOut('150');
      }, 1200);
      //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
      someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
  });
```

Comment: This might fit better at Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @calvinf: Code Review SE is for working code only. It seems a debugging/helping question.

Comment: @palacsint: okay, good information, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    var timeoutIds=0;  
    $(".play").on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).next(".more-info").fadeIn(600);
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        var someElement = $(this);
        timeoutIds = setTimeout(function(){
            someElement.next(".more-info").fadeOut('150');
        }, 1200); 
    });

    $(".more-info").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeoutIds);
        $(this).find(".the-tooltip").fadeIn('150');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var someElement = $(this);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            someElement.find(".the-tooltip").fadeOut('150');
        }, 300);
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDzVN/4/) (Due to the changes of source the demo is not working anymore.).

Comment: Hi Sheikh Heera, i did try the code but now they will not fadeOut anymore

Comment: I would like that the ( i ) would fadeOut too.

Comment: hi Sheikh Heera, your example did not work :/ but i have now changed my code and it almost works there is one little bug. [New code jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pullapooh/GJt8W/2/) | [Bug video example](http://www.screenr.com/tIJ8) | [Website](http://www.midnightlisteners.com/)

Comment: @Pullapooh, it was working yesterday, may be you have changed something in the css. i've tested the demo last night and it was working.